# How to set anchor for label in web form application in code? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I wanted to set anchor for label but in properties of label i could not find anchor field and how can set it by code maybe in style?

I tried to write in page_load label.Anchor but it cant find this class.

```
    .labelName{float: left; text-align: center; margin-left: 810px ; margin-top: 20px;width: 150px; }

  </style>


<div class="labelName">
    <asp:Label ID="lblGameName" runat="server" Text="Huina Game">     </asp:Label>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use asp:HyperLink that render as anchor  or asp:LinkButton if you need to do a postback with server side handler

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="labelWithLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="https://stackoverflow.com" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>

<asp:LinkButton ID="labelWithLinkAndPostback" runat="server" OnClick="ServerSideHandler_click" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I want to place a label in the middle of screen and if user changes the size of browser page the label's size will change and also locations.   it will be always in the middle , how to do that.